# How does git work with project ( Android Studio )

Tags: android, git, github

I have a project .rar has size 22MB.
The Project was opened by Android Studio and push to github.
I Downloaded from git my project but this time my project size only 3MB.
Can someone explain me why is it diffrent size?
and How does git work with Android Studio

Comment: I assume Android studio ignores media files and other binary objects (as you generally should always do when using version control).

Comment: Still the same project or diffrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't track large binary files in a Git repo. If you absolutely have to have them in your repository, use an extension like [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) or [git-media](https://github.com/alebedev/git-media).

Comment: but it is Android Studio plugin... so it's useless right?

Comment: No, you can still use these extensions. `git` is an external program that gets invoked by the Android Studio plugin, so you are free to modify your global configuration as you please.

Comment: So you mean i shouldn't use `git` to `push` a large file right?. Only use git for `update`

Comment: Yes, you should avoid adding large files to your commits. Merge operations will become slow and use a lot of memory (I've learned from experience haha)

Comment: So advice for Ubuntu `git` app please